# Регулярное выражение для удаления тегов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, replace

**Важно!** Нужно удалять не все теги, некоторые должны остаться в белом списке: `a, b, i, u, ul, li, ol, img`

Вот мой код: (он удаляет все теги)

```
pole = pole.replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?--!?>/g, '').replace(/<\/?[a-z][^>]*(>|$)/gi, '');
```

И еще нужно удалять атрибуты в тегах из белого списка.

Comment: Судя по всему, речь про браузерный javascript. А это значит, что у вас есть идеальный инструмент для решения вашей задачи - DOM и его api. Немного рекурсии и самой простой логики и вы решите свою задачу без использования регулярных выражений. Ну и, разумеется, непременная ссылка - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1510966

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = "<a class=test><i><b><pre></pre></b></div><img src=/test.png>";

text = text.replace(/<(\/?)([a-z]+)[^>]*(>|$)/gi, function(match, slash, tag) {
  if (["a", "b", "i", "u", "ul", "li", "ol", "img"].indexOf(tag) < 0) {
    // тег не из белого списка удаляем подчистую
    return '';
  }

  // хороший тег оставим без атрибутов
  return '<' + slash + tag + '>';
});

console.log(text); 
// выведёт <a><i><b></b><img>
```

Конечно же этот пример вам нужно будет доработать, например, для тегов написанных прописными буквами. Также определённо вам не нужен тег `<img>` без атрибута `src`.

Это всё если забыть о том что вы решаете [не ту задачу не теми инструментами](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Что если в атрибуте тега будет `<`?..

Comment: Спасибо. В атрибуте не будет `<`, это я делаю форматирование текста после редактора, то есть всё что он делает, это вставляет `<p style="...">` и т.д. А как добавить в исключение атрибут в `<img>`?

Answer (score 1):

Увы, джаваскрипта не знаю, поэтому пример написал на Руби:

```
str = <<'EOT'
Это <!--пример текста--> с 
<a href="#">какой-то</a> <br>разметкой <br /> 
<b class="11">и</b> <amg src="1"> 
<area>непарными</area> <strong>
тегами</strong> и, <!--коментами-->, 
<ul id="w"> <li id="id" class="class">1</li></ul>. 
<u class="ну и даже так" />
EOT

puts str.gsub(/(<(?!\/?a\b)(?!\/?b\b)(?!\/?i\b)(?!\/?u\b)(?!\/?ul\b)(?!\/?li\b)(?!\/?ol\b)(?!\/?img\b)[^>]+\s*\/?>)/m,'')
        .gsub(/(<a\b|b\b|i\b|u\b|ul\b|li\b|ol\b|img\b)(\s[^>]+?)(\s*\/?>)/m,'\\1\\3')
```

Результат:

```
Это  с 
<a>какой-то</a> разметкой  
<b>и</b>  
непарными 
тегами и, , 
<ul> <li>1</li></ul>. 
<u />
```

**В итоге**

Первый регэксп с глобальной заменой удаляет все теги не из белого листа:

```
/(<(?!\/?a\b)(?!\/?b\b)(?!\/?i\b)(?!\/?u\b)(?!\/?ul\b)(?!\/?li\b)(?!\/?ol\b)(?!\/?img\b)[^>]+\s*\/?>)/m,''
```

Второй регэксп чистит теги из белого листа:

```
/(<a\b|b\b|i\b|u\b|ul\b|li\b|ol\b|img\b)(\s[^>]+?)(\s*\/?>)/m,'\\1\\3'
```

[Онлайн на ideone](http://ideone.com/YYcQpU)

Таким образом, программые циклы не нужны, регэкспы могут все сами :)

PS. Естественно, если регистр не важен - в регэкспы добавляем моификатор "i"